# Upsampling algorithm too slow

Tags: matlab

I have to come up with an upsampling algorithm for a project and cannot use Matlab's built in `upsample` function. I came up with the following function but it just runs forever when I use a 13 second, 16-bit song sampled at 44.1kHz. Please let me know how I can improve the efficiency of this algorithm:

```
    x = desired_Fs/original_Fs; %desired and original sampling frequencies
    len = x * length(y); %y is the input signal
    q = x - 1;

    for i = 1:x:len
       for j = length(y):-1:i+1
            y(j + q) = y(j);
       end
       for k = i+1:1:i+q
            y(k) = 0;
       end
    end `
    upsampled_audio = y;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really a StackOverflow question, not Signal Processing, but since you are here...

```
upsampleFactor = desired_Fs/original_Fs; %desired and original sampling frequencies
output = zeros(length(input)*upsampleFactor,1);
output(1:upsampleFactor:end) = input;
```

The above code assumes that upsampleFactor is an integer.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should use informative variable names. For example, use "upsample_ratio" instead of x, "inSignal" instead of y etc. This will make your code much easier to read and understand.

Second, you should avoid using for loops in matlab if possible, and especially don't use nested for loops, since they take very long time in matlab.

Third, you overuse the variable y. Use intermediate variables to keep temporary and result values.

Forth, your algorithm concept is wrong in case the upsampling ratio is not a whole number.

Specifically for your code, start by replacing the inner loops with array operations:

`vec = length(y):-1:i+1;
y(vec+q) = y(vec);
y(i+1:1:i+1) = 0;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I changed the variable names to just x and y as I didn't want to use my confusing names for it. 

My upsampling ratio is always going to be a whole number. 

I replaced the inner loops with array operations like you said but the code still runs for a long time. I tested it to work for short signals and it does match the results obtained using Matlab's built-in `upsample` function. Is there any way I can avoid using the outer for loop as well?